# tinyMCE 4.0 custom button onclick no longer working

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to update one of my WordPress plugins where I create a tinyMCE button and open up a thickbox on click.

I've just tried switching over to a basic example for testing, and can't get this to work either.

```
    onclick : function() {
        ed.insertContent('Main button');
    }
```

Comment: Try `editor.on('click', function(e) { alert("Click") });`.